# Reusing(user click) the same HTML Anchor (#) in the same page

Tags: html

I'm having to develop a html page on a platform called Unily which doesn't allow me to use any JS or CSS (other than inline). The page is long and I want to use anchors for them to navigate back to the top of the page. This is fine when you click top the first time, but because the url is now #TOP if you scroll down and click on a #top link again, it does nothing.

Is there any way at all without using JS that I can get this to work multiple times?

Comment: no. an anchor must be unique in the document

Comment: You can use inline-javascript. No platform should disallow this because javascript is executed in the browser when the page loads. See my answer below for some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline javascript to do this.

```html
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function scrollTo(anchor) {
       location.hash = anchor;
       location.hash = "";
  }
  </script>
  <style>
      div a { display: block; min-height: 1000px; background-color: blue;}
  </style>

  <body>
    <div>
        <a id="loc1">text</a><br>
    </div>

    <a href="" onClick="scrollTo('loc1')">go to Loc 1</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above snippet doesn't work when embedded but you can easily copy it to an html file on your computer and run it in your local browser. It works and doesn't even modify the URL so you can avoid ugly `#`'s in your URL.